# Corda Shell throws exception for `run vaultQuery` - Cash.State

Tags: corda

`run vaultQuery contractStateType: net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash.State`

Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `java.lang.Class`, pr
oblem: net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash.State
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
Please try 'man run' to learn what syntax is acceptable

Comment: Is the `finance` CorDapp installed on your node? Run `flow list` and see whether the cash flows are listed.

Comment: I can see all cash flows listed:
`net.corda.finance.flows.CashConfigDataFlow
net.corda.finance.flows.CashExitFlow
net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueAndPaymentFlow
net.corda.finance.flows.CashIssueFlow
net.corda.finance.flows.CashPaymentFlow`

I also tried with sample example Shell, and getting same error - https://github.com/corda/cordapp-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for accessing `State` inside `Cash` is:

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$State
```

Note the `$`.

Comment: Oh!, you are correct. The `State` is sub-class of `Cash` class. I missed it. Thanks.